# Bug in converting from a large long to a float in Java on OSX?

Tags: java, math, casting

I'm running JDK 1.7 on OS/X, 64-bit.  This is, I think, a bug... because it does not occur on Android nor on an Ubuntu Linux box.  Maybe it's specific to my x86 processor (just purchased earlier this year)...not sure.

Basically, I want a time... in either nanoseconds or milliseconds... expressed as a float.  When I run the below code, and cast the long returned by System.nanoTime() to a float, the float stays constant.  The same problem occurs with System.currentTimeMillis().  The time (a long) is changing of course... but the cast to a float is completely and utterly failing.  It even fails with a large long that I manually enter as 1404434478024L.

```
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { 
//          long timeL = 1404434478024L;
            long timeL = java.lang.System.nanoTime();
//          long timeL = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

            float timeF = timeL;
            System.out.printf("%d: TimeL is %d.  timeF is %f. ", i, timeL, timeF);  

            Long pTimeL = new Long(timeL);
            float timeF2 = pTimeL.floatValue();
            System.out.printf("   And timeF2 is %f.\n", timeF2);    
        } 

Output:

0: TimeL is 1404435840046330000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
1: TimeL is 1404435840046601000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
2: TimeL is 1404435840046870000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
3: TimeL is 1404435840047149000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
4: TimeL is 1404435840047417000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
5: TimeL is 1404435840047690000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
6: TimeL is 1404435840047959000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
7: TimeL is 1404435840048230000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
8: TimeL is 1404435840048517000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
9: TimeL is 1404435840048813000.  timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000.    And timeF2 is 1404435888972234750.000000.
```

Here's the fix / workaround that I've come up with.

```
        System.out.printf("\n Now, with the fix:\n");           
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { 
//          long timeL = 1404434478024L;
//          long timeL = java.lang.System.nanoTime();
            long timeL = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeL = timeL % 1000000;    
            // Eliminate the high-order word... 
            // That is, keep only the lower digits under 1,000,000 seconds.  

            float timeF = timeL;
            System.out.printf("%d: TimeL is %d.  timeF is %f. ", i, timeL, timeF);  

            Long pTimeL = new Long(timeL);
            float timeF2 = pTimeL.floatValue();
            System.out.printf("   And timeF2 is %f.\n", timeF2);    
        }

Output:

 Now, with the fix:
0: TimeL is 840049.  timeF is 840049.000000.    And timeF2 is 840049.000000.
1: TimeL is 840049.  timeF is 840049.000000.    And timeF2 is 840049.000000.
2: TimeL is 840049.  timeF is 840049.000000.    And timeF2 is 840049.000000.
3: TimeL is 840049.  timeF is 840049.000000.    And timeF2 is 840049.000000.
4: TimeL is 840050.  timeF is 840050.000000.    And timeF2 is 840050.000000.
5: TimeL is 840050.  timeF is 840050.000000.    And timeF2 is 840050.000000.
6: TimeL is 840050.  timeF is 840050.000000.    And timeF2 is 840050.000000.
7: TimeL is 840050.  timeF is 840050.000000.    And timeF2 is 840050.000000.
8: TimeL is 840051.  timeF is 840051.000000.    And timeF2 is 840051.000000.
9: TimeL is 840051.  timeF is 840051.000000.    And timeF2 is 840051.000000.
```

Anyone else wanna try running the first code extract above and letting me know whether timeF is changing for you?  That is, whether you're not experiencing the issue that I am?

And, what's going on?  Is there a better workaround than the one I've come up with?

And, is this a bug?  At what layer?

Comment: I suggest you study about how floating point numbers are stored. They cannot store a number to exact precision like integral numbers, such as `long`, can.

Comment: Change from float to double.  A float only carries about 6 digits of precision.

Comment: You're sure this worked on Android and Ubuntu?

Comment: @user2357112 - I'm guessing his code on Android and Ubuntu used double vs float.

Comment: Or maybe the nanoTime values were smaller. What were the values that worked?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!  On Android & Ubuntu, I was probably just getting a smaller return value from System.nanoTime() to avoid the problem.  What surprises me most is that float has such limited precision (just 7 decimal digits or so).  I was particularly surprised that my output APPEARS to have 18 or so digits of precision ("timeF is 1404435888972234750.000000"), but only the top 7 decimal digits are a correct conversion from the long.  The other 11 digits 88972234750 are all basically random.  Why not zero them out at least?

Answer (score 2):

A `float` is 32 bits long.  A `long` is **64 bits** long.

The main issue is that you're losing some precision when converting between the two types.  More specifically, [this case in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) is covered explicitly:

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long
>   value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result
>   may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this
>   case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded
>   version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode
>   (§4.2.4).

You're getting the ["round-to-nearest"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of misuse of `float`, rather than a bug. The `float` type has limited precision, 24 bits for normal numbers, equivalent to a bit over 7 decimal digits. Your `long` values are all the same in the most significant 12 decimal digits, so they all convert to the same `float`.

Suppressing the most significant 32 bits could have bad effects if there were a carry into them during your time interval.

`System.nanoTime()` has no absolute significance. Only relative values and differences are meaningful. I suggest subtracting the first nanoTime result from each nanoTime result in `long`, before converting to `double` or `float` for subsequent calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll write it as an answer:

Here is the output that I got:

```
0: TimeL is 19799440493105.  timeF is 19799440621568.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799440621568.000000.
1: TimeL is 19799461838486.  timeF is 19799461593088.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799461593088.000000.
2: TimeL is 19799462215508.  timeF is 19799461593088.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799461593088.000000.
3: TimeL is 19799462573212.  timeF is 19799461593088.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799461593088.000000.
4: TimeL is 19799462915822.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.
5: TimeL is 19799463295259.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.
6: TimeL is 19799463587157.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.                    
7: TimeL is 19799463867585.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.
8: TimeL is 19799464241890.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.
9: TimeL is 19799464598084.  timeF is 19799463690240.000000.    And timeF2 is 19799463690240.000000.
```

The code above works perfectly, but the issue might be that the time you have is too big to convert to float, so try using doubles instead.

Hope this helps:
Classic

Comment: Note that several different longs converted to the same float.

Comment: "A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4)."